# C# TPL lock shared object between tasks vs populating it with the results from Task(TResult) tasks

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

In my use of the Task Parallel Library in .net 4.0 I am wondering what is the best way to merge results from my parallel tasks, normally i would require a lock on a shared object between them, but now i wondering if the `Task(TResult)` class and merging at the end is a better solution? Below I have the two approaches i consider:

TPL with lock:

```
public MyObject DoWork()
{
    var result = new MyObject();
    var resultLock = new object();
    var taskArray = new Task[this._objects.Length];
    for (var i = 0; i < taskArray.Length; i++)
    {
        taskArray[i] = new Task((obj) =>
            {
                var _o = obj as AnObject;
                var tmpResult = _o.DoTaskWork();
                lock (resultLock)
                    result.Add(tmpResult);
            }, this._objects[i]);
    }
    Task.WaitAll(taskArray);
    return result;
}
```

And TPL with the merging at the end:

```
public MyObject DoWork()
{
    var taskArray = new Task<String>[this._objects.Length];
    for (var i = 0; i < taskArray.Length; i++)
    {
        taskArray[i] = new Task<String>((obj) =>
        {
            var _o = obj as AnObject;
            return _o.DoTaskWork();
        }, this._objects[i]);
    }
    Task<String>.WaitAll(taskArray);
    var result = new MyObject();
    for (var i = 0; i < taskArray.Length; i++)
        result.Add(taskArray[i].Result);
    return result;
}
```

Is there a right or wrong solution or what is a best practice (other possible solution to merging results from parallel tasks are most welcome)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using Parallel LINQ (which does all the nasty stuff for you), you could boil this down to a single line or so:

```
var workResults = _objects.AsParallel().Select(DoTaskWork);
foreach(var r in workResults)
{
    result.Add(r);
}
```

Comment: Hi, I really like the suggested solution, simple and LINQ'ed, but if it is the case that i would use the Task library, what would be preferable!

Comment: In which case, I would use one of the concurrent collections (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.concurrent.aspx) and add straight into it from the body of the task. Don't forget that PLinq uses TPL under the hood.

Comment: Okay, the ConcurrentDictionary would be something that fits very well. How does PLINQ perform, because i have often read that using LINQ to query the data structures is expensive in relation to time, is there some up/down side in PLINQ when time becomes a very important factor?

Comment: I'd say a benchmark against your load would be the best way to establish what's fastest. I'm not fond of "Linq is slow" type statements. I imagine quite a lot of work went into PLinq with regards to optimising the partitioning of data and the collating of the results. It's *probably* going to be more efficient than hand-rolled merging, but once again, only a benchmark against your specific load will reveal what's best.